# Read All Dead Letter Queue messages

Tags: azureservicebus

I am able to read DLQ messages. There are 4000 of them. And I am sure I am only able to read 250 or 270 of them. Rest of the messages just repeat themselves. I think it has to do with receive time:

```
IMessage msg = deadletterReceiver.receive(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
```

I do it for seconds, or minutes, doesn't matter. I am only able to read 250-260 of them and then the same ones repeat. Is there a different way to read all 4k DLQ messages?

I don't want to do this `deadletterReceiver.completeAsync(message.getLockToken());` **yet** as it will delete the messages and those DLQ messages are priceless.

Comment: Are you reading messages _and_ completing? If not, based of the `MaxLockDuration`, you will start getting the same messages again.

Comment: No I am not completing them. I will look up MaxLockDuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the following - dead-letter queue has a `MaxLockDuration` during which you're supposed to complete message processing. If you don't, the message will re-appear in the queue and you'll consume it again. The maximum locking time for a message is 5 minutes. You could read in batches, do what you need to do with those dead-lettered messages, and complete them. All within the `MaxLockDuration` time.

I also recommend to ensure you do it [transactionally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions) in order not to lose any dead-lettered messages.

Edited by the questioner:

This is the most relevant part in the document:

> When a message is locked, other clients receiving from the same queue or subscription can take on locks and retrieve the next available messages not under active lock. When the lock on a message is explicitly released or when the lock expires, the message pops back up at or near the front of the retrieval order for redelivery.

edit2: I don't how this important document got lost: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement) it is again.